# AngularJS Error: ng:areq Bad Argument

Tags: angularjs, module

I have the following three angularjs scripts:

```
/config.js
/authentication/LoginCtrl.js
/authentication/loginFactoyr.js
```

App `ristoreApp` is defined in config.js.

//config.js

```
angular.module('ristoreApp', ['ngRoute'])

.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
//  $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('httpInterceptor');

    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', { 
            templateUrl: 'authentication/login.html', 
            controller: 'LoginCtrl' 
        })
        .when('/home', { 
            templateUrl: 'home.html', 
        })
        .otherwise({ 
            redirectTo: '/login' 
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

My controller calls the app by "angular.module":

```
angular.module('ristoreApp', [])
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'loginFactory', function($scope, $location, loginFactory){
    $scope.authenticate = function() {
        loginFactory.login($scope.username, $scope.password)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $location.path('/home');
        }, function errorCallBack(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $location.path('login');
        });
    }
}]);
```

Got the error "Error: ng:areq Bad Argument"

```
Argument 'LoginCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

Why does it say my controller is not a function? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  Remove the quotes on `LoginCtrl`.

```
controller: LoginCtrl
```

Then, define the controller as:

```
var LoginCtrl = app.controller("LoginCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) { /* etc... */}]);
```

Comment: What quotes do I remove? I changed my controller to `app = angular.module('ristoreApp', []);
var LoginCtrol = app.controller("LoginCtrl", ['$scope',...` but it didn't help

Comment: You have to remove the quotes.  `controller: 'LoginCtrl'` should be `controller: LoginCtrl`